# EntityManager configuration in each DAO

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I understand that this is a very long question, but i wanted to ask everything because i'm
stuck with these things for more than 2 weeks and i'm in a situation to solve this within
this week. Please guide me in this matter.

I'm Using EclipseLink jpa version 2, Spring 3, jdk6, MySQL5 and tomcat7.

I have configured the following in each of my DAO classes.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

I have the following in my Spring xml:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"  id="dataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxxx"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter" >
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect"/>
```

From Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="xxxxx" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<-- class mappings -->
</persistence-unit>
```

I've got few confusion about what i have done:

1. Is the `EntityManager` injected by Spring? (I understand that `@PersistenceContext` is a 
   J2EE annotation, so wondering whether it is injected without Spring's contribution).
2. As i have already mentioned, i have injected `EntityManager` in all the DAO classes. Is
   this a good practice? or should i make it Singleton by having a separate class like 
   `PersistenceManager`, which has `EntityManager` attribute wired, and have
   `getEntityManager()` method?
3. As you can see above, i have configured Spring transactions. But when i do CRUD
   operations continuously for 2-3 times, application gets stuck and fails with EclipseLink
   exception saying unable to get lock, timeout etc. Am i doing anything wrong here or
   missing any transaction configurations??
4. With the above configurations, i can only use `@Transactional` annotation with default 
   values which are `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT`. If i change these for any other
   values, such as  `@Transactional(PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE)` etc,
   application throws exception as Custom isolation levels are not supported. Again, am
   i missing any configurations?

   Thanks.

Comment: For #3 can you include the exception stack trace, and the SQL log.  Are you updating the database from multiple client concurrently?

Comment: The application should work for multiple clients concurrently, but so far i have tested only with one client, but even for this case, issue #3 is happening. Part of exception log: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
Error Code: 1205.

Comment: Part of SQL log: [EL Warning]: 2011-09-08 19:57:10.828--UnitOfWork(19307203)--Thread(Thread[http-8080-exec-10,5,main])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
Error Code: 1205
Call: INSERT INTO xxxx(xxxx, xxxx) VALUES (?, ?)
 bind => [3151, 7401]
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="INSERT INTO xxxx(xxxx, xxxx) VALUES (?, ?)")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes, spring recognizes the `@PersistenceContext` annotation and injects the entity manager
2. Spring takes care of that - it injects the same `EntityManager` instance in all DAOs. In fact, it injects a proxy so that each request uses a different entity manager.
3. Normally everything should run fine. You need `<tx:annotation-driven />` in order to use `@Transactional`
4. JPA only supports the default isolation level. You can work this around by customizing the spring jpa dialect, but there's nothing built-in. The way to go is extend `XJpaDialect` (in your case X=EclipseLink), override the `beingTransaction`, obtain the `Connection` (in an eclipse-link specific way), set the desired isolation level (accessible through the transaction definition), and configure this as a property of your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`:

   ```
   <property name="jpaDialect">
       <bean class="com.foo.util.persistence.EclipseLinkExtendedJpaDialect" />
   </property>
   ```

Comment: Thanks Bozho, your answers cleared my confusions. Can you please elaborate on customizing the spring jpa dialect for different isolation mechanisms??? I didn't get this point...

Comment: I still didn't get the full answer for #4. Can you please elaborate on customizing the spring jpa dialect for different isolation mechanisms???

Comment: it's not that trivial. Are you really sure you need it? I added a few more pointers

Comment: Hi Bozho, I have one entity manager and I want to configure with 2 data source/2 schema.There is one persistence unit is available and we can not create one more,because we are using our own existing api. Limitation is we cannot create one more entity manager also, please suggest how we can use this 2 schema. One is working but when we are trying for 2nd one its failing.please suggests.

Comment: Should my dao look like this? `@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public UserDaoImpl(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerfactory) {
        this.entityManager = entityManagerfactory.createEntityManager();
    }`